# How do I make the Hyper V Manager Client GUI "Stretch the Display"? VMware workstation and Virtualbox do this

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

Does anyone know how to make the Hyper V Manager to stretch the display for any workstation that you connect to. Is there a way to ask this as a feature request for 2019 and future versions?

I know that VirtualBox allows it by pressing the ControlKey + C, and VMware Workstation allow it via highlight a VM > Settings > Display > Stretch mode >  Free Stretch.

How can we do this in Hyper-V. My Eyes really hurt a lot because of the large monitor I have, and I want the views to be stretched. Does anyone know?

Comment: So I tried to play with the settings but even the new Windows 2016 Evaluation cd when you install the hyper-v role, and then try to open a VM doesnt have a option to stretch the screen... Any ideas guys?

Comment: When you mean by "Stretch the display" to "resize the remote window": Unfortunately the Hyper-V Manager has no resize features.

Comment: Who can I email to ask for this request in a future release? It will help our eyes for those of us whom are disabled. Thank you kindly